# Azure ADF pipeline error running a sql query with timestamp as string

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

My query looks like this

```
DECLARE @TimeStamp CHAR(26)

SET @TimeStamp = @{activity('GetLastUpdate').
OUTPUT.firstRow.LastUpdateDateTime}

SELECT @TimeStamp
    ,*
    ,GetDate() AS TS_Deleted
FROM dbo.Customer
WHERE UpdatedTimeStamp > CAST(@TimeStamp AS CHAR(26))
```

I am using copy data activity to copy on-premise data to the `Azure SQL database`. The source system has `timestamp` data as the character (`'2003-12-18 16:25:00.000'`). When I run the above query I get the following error

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> 'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near
> '.27'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near '.27'.,},],'

The value being returned is `2020-11-12-23.54.47.987193`.

When I use the preview feature of the task and use the same value for
`@{activity('GetLastUpdate').output.firstRow.LastUpdateDateTime}`

with single quotes it works but if I remove the single quotes it gives the same error as above. I need somehow to mimic the same functionality (using single quotes with the above SQL query.

Please do remember my source data has timestamp as `Char(26)`
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach would be to use a stored procedure at source side to get data by passing load date as parameter to it, below is implementation of it

[image]